# OracleDataReader is not defined using Oracle.ManageAccess.Client asp.net VB

Tags: oracle, vb.net, undefined

```
Imports Oracle.DataAcess.Client

Public Function Data() As OracleDataReader 
 //CODE HERE
End Function
```

Above code works if I use **Imports Oracle.DataAccess.Client** . But if I use **Imports Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client** it says OracleDataReader is not defined and I'm pretty sure I have it in my reference and I call  and OracleDataReader from Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client and it works fine in normal call but I get an error if I make it as return type function

Comment: Did you install the ODP.NET Managed Driver? Which version of .NET framework do you use?

Comment: I installed the latest Oracle.ManageDataAcess.Client from nuget package I use the 4.x .NET and V.S 2019